# hide and show specific divs with css wordpress

Tags: html, css, show-hide

I am trying to hide two specific divs and show them on click.

[Divs hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ3yL.jpg)
[Divs shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Lc4.jpg)

The Code I have so far:

```js
.testit#detail-513{
display:none;
}
.testit#detail-515{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<tr id="detail-<?php the_id();?>" class="testit">

<button class="testit">Show the two hidden id´s</button>
```

What do I have to add to the button?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a toggle option, here is a simple to use toggle option which is easily customisable:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("toggle");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
#toggle {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle">
  <tr id="detail-<?php the_id();?>">
    <p>Test</p>
  </tr>
</div>

<span onclick="myFunction()" tabindex="0">Toggle</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. The problem is that I am trying to place a button inside the first row & hide / show the other two rows when I click on it. As you can see, the first code <tr id="detail-<?php the_id();?>" class="testit"> generates new Id´s per post. So the the two rows are named #detail-513 and #detail-515 . So on click I am trying to show or hide them and have em hidden by default. I updated the Picture for better understanding.